# How can I make Symfony 6 dynamic router match URLs with question marks in them?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm rewriting one old website into Symfony. There is requirement that old URL addresses stay so I dumped them into database and wrote custom dynamic route loader. The problem is that some URLs contain question mark and Symfony seems to ommit anything behind question mark as it thinks it is a parameter. How can I solve it? Here is current code of DynamicRouteLoader:

```php
namespace App\RouteLoader;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use RuntimeException;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use App\Entity\Route as CustomRoute;

class DynamicRouteLoader extends Loader
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    private bool $loaded = false;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function load($resource, $type = null): RouteCollection
    {
        if ($this->loaded) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Dynamic routes are already loaded.');
        }

        $routesCollection = new RouteCollection;

        /** @var CustomRoute[] $routes */
        $routes = $this->entityManager->getRepository(CustomRoute::class)->findAll();

        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            foreach (['cs', 'sk', 'en', 'de', 'ru'] as $lang) {
                $path = $route->getUrl($lang);
                $defaults = [
                    '_controller' => 'App\Controller\\' . $route->getController() . 'Controller::' . $route->getAction(),
                    '_locale' => $lang,
                ];
                $name = strtolower($route->getController()) . '_' . $route->getAction();
                if ($route->getParameters() !== null) {
                    $defaults['id'] = $route->getParameters();
                    $name .= '_' . $route->getParameters();
                }
                $name .= '_' . $lang;
                $routesCollection->add($name, new Route($path, $defaults));
            }
        }

        $this->loaded = true;

        return $routesCollection;
    }

    public function supports($resource, $type = null): bool
    {
        return $type === 'dynamic';
    }
}
```

Example of Error message: No route found for "GET [http://web.local/page.asp"](http://web.local/page.asp%22) when I try address "http://web.local/page.asp?lang=sk". The only solution I can think of is replace question marks with underscores via .htaccess.

Comment: I would just assume you'd register the pages, and then handle the query string logic in the route itself?

Comment: What do you mean by route itself? Like in controller?

Comment: By "route", I meant the method that is invoked for a URL as defined in `'App\Controller\\' . $route->getController() . 'Controller::' . $route->getAction()`. So `/path.asp`, `/path.asp?a=b` and `/path.asp?a=b&c=d` are all the same route, and you can inspect the `Request` object if you need to act upon the query string in some fashion.

Comment: Well I inspected Symfony source code and located the line which I need to change. It is in class UrlMatcher, method matchRequest, change $request->getPathInfo() to $request->getRequestUri(). Now I have problem with registering custom url matcher... `Service "App\Routing\QueryStringUrlMatcher" not found: the container inside "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\ServiceLocator" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "kernel" service.`

Comment: Are you saying you are directly modifying Symfony's `UrlMatcher` class?

Comment: No I need to modify it via child classs